# How to store files outside Rails app folder in CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have this dir structure on my hosting:

```
— my_project_folder
— — current (symlink to latest release folder)

— — releases
— — — [ app folder: cap deploy 1 ]
— — — — — app
— — — — — config
— — — — — ...

— — — [ app folder: cap deploy 2 ]
— — — [ app folder: cap deploy n ]

— — shared
```

I want to store uploaded with CarrierWave files in shared folder.
What paths I should put for store_dir and cache_dir?

```
def store_dir
  '/what/path/to/uploads'
end

def cache_dir
  '/what/path/to/cache'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store them in the default folder - `/public/uploads/` if i remember correctly, but you should symlink this folder with the shared folder on every deploy.

You can use this capistrano [recipe.](https://github.com/pferdefleisch/capistrano-recipes/blob/master/carrierwave.rb)